# My android's app name shows phonegap plugins name, why?

Tags: android, cordova

I used barcodescanner plugin in my app!
But when I deploy to my phone!
And I saw my app's name becomes to plugins' name?

How do i fix it?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found the answer!
Because I've not defined /res/values-zh-rTW/strings.xml in my app,
but the plugin did!
So just add this file into my app, and done!